# Get return code from nuget update command

Tags: c#, nuget

Our CI pipeline runs this command to update a specific package reference to its latest release:

```
nuget update Solution.sln -Id [Package Id] -ConfigFile [CONFIG] -Version [VERSION]
```

If this fails to find the version specified, we see this in the output:

```
WARNING: Package '[PACKAGE]' is not found in the following primary source(s): '[SOURCE]'.
Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
```

However, crucially the %ERRORLEVEL% return code is still 0.  I can't see any way to tell nuget to throw this as an error.

Is there another workaround?

This is

- using NuGet Version: 4.1.0.2450 and also 4.8.1.5435
- building a .Net 4.5.2 component

Comment: A quick browse through the source code and it should be setting the return code to `1`, are you sure it's not working?

Comment: Yes, 100% certain :(.  If you can point me to the code perhaps I can debug locally ?

Comment: https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client

Answer (score 0):

What version of NuGet are you using? It appears this was fixed in NuGet 3.2 so you might be running an older version.

Please have a look at this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1186

Comment: 4.1.0.2450, I've added to original question aswell